# Access to removed element in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have:

```
<div v-if="page=='main'"  key="1">
   x
</div>

<div v-if="page=='about'"  key="2">
   y
</div>

<div v-if="page=='contact'"  key="3">
   z
</div>
```

However, when the third div (`contact`) is visible, I can’t access the first or second div, as those DOM elements are removed at all.
How can I access other divs, when for example the third one is visible?

Comment: v-show? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Comment: @JacobGoh thanks! post as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show).

`v-if` controls whether the element is rendered.

`v-show` controls whether the element has a `display:none` CSS property.

Comment: btw, in case of v-if, is there any way to access that dom in vue memory (or anywhere)?

Comment: @T.Todua I don't think so. What is it that you are trying to get ?

Comment: Try to look throug vueJS Instance Lifecycle Hooks, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks, there you can manipulate application in different state of component rendering

Answer (score 2):

Vue.js works with a **virtual DOM**. Since you write Vue.js code, it renders the page as it is, as the v-if code allows.

Those elements that are not subject to the v-if will be left out of the rendered DOM, to make the **browser more efficient**.

You can use `v-show`. `v-show` only toggles the display CSS property of the element.